# Django count records with aggregate

Tags: python, django, aggregate-functions

I have field like this:

[image: Showing field value]

I want all records count with all tags for example

```
sale = Sale.objects.using('read_rep') \
        .filter(tags__name__in=['Device','Mobile']) \
        .aggregate(
         **{total: Count('pk', for status, _ in ['Device','Mobile']}
 )


Device - 2 Mobile-5
```

It is difficult to count records with all tags because tags are being store in only one field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try values and annotate approach.

```
sale = Sale.objects.using('read_rep') \
        .filter(tags__name__in=['Device','Mobile']).values(
                'tags__name'
            ).annotate(
                tags_count=Count('tags__name')
            )
```

Which gives:

```
[
    {'tags__name': "Device", 'tags_count': 3},
    {'tags__name': "Mobile", 'tags_count': 5},
]
```